# Netbeans for C++ (gcc 64bit)

Tags: c, netbeans

How can I make Netbeans work with the GCC 64 bit compiler?

Comment: It looks like you just have to download http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/6.0/final/ , there is no package or Netbean internal plugi system...

Answer (score 2):

Net Beans can be obtained from the following URL:

http://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: And what about the GCC 64 bit compiler ?

I need to install it before or after I install netbeans ?

And how do I set the GCC 64 bit compiler to be the default compiler in netbeans ?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Consider Googling it, also.

Answer (score 1):

After the download is complete..
Make a executable file

Step 1: cd downloads

Step 2: chmod +x netbeans-8.2-cpp-linux-x86.sh

Step 3: sh ./netbeans-8.2-cpp-linux-x86.sh

Because I installed only c/c++ package,  hence is the name. Though you can choose the entire bundle too..

Answer (score 0):

For gcc, make and gdb just run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb
```

That's all the Netbeans C++ plugin requires. To get it installed, see:

- http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/cpp-setup-instructions.html

The whole "64bit" thing is a red herring. By default `gcc` will run in 64bit mode if you're running in a 64bit environment.